# Best way to write Combination logic in SQL or MVC for multiple select options

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I, want to write the best combination login either SQL store procedure or ASP.net for the following combination diagram.

[image: combination diagram]

Each field in the diagram has 4 combinations. So, total it will be 20 combinations. I, don't want to write 20 if else statement in SQL server or c#.

Here is the UI for the logic.
[image: image describtion]

The user can either select Quotation no or combination of 20 etc. I, don't want to write 20 if else statement.

Is their any better way to write a statement in SQL or C# to make it better.

For example
the user can select from either Quotation no or agency name or start date or end date or combination of two or more field.

What is the best way to write the algorithm?
Here is the combination

1- Search By only Quotation No

2- Search By only Agency No

3- Search By only Start Date

4- Search By only End Date

5- Search By only contract No

6 - Quotation No + Agency No

7 - Quotation No + Start Date

8 - Quotation No + End Date

9 -  Select by All fields

Comment: You just build the query on the fly. `IQueryable<T> data = db.T; if (agencyName.HasValue) { data = data.Where(x => x.AgencyName == agencyName.Value)` etc.

Comment: You don't mean 20 combinations, rather it's 4^5 so 1024 combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a similar problem some time ago while trying to perform a search using many filters. The best solution I found was to use a dynamic SQL query, in which the statement is built based on the parameters.

The select clause of the sql statement is static but the from clause and the where clause is based on the parameters.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SearchQuotation
(
    @QuotationNo INT,
    @AgencyName VARCHAR(50),
    @StartDate DATETIME,
    @EndDate DATETIME,
    @Term INT
)
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
        SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM Quotations WHERE 1 = 1'

        DECLARE @ParametersDefinition NVARCHAR(4000)
        SELECT @ParametersDefinition = N'@QuotationNoParameter INT,
                                        @AgencyNameParameter VARCHAR(50),
                                        @StartDateParameter DATETIME,
                                        @EndDateParameter DATETIME,
                                        @TermParameter INT'

        IF @QuotationNo IS NOT NULL
            SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N' AND QuotationNo = @QuotationNoParameter '

        IF @AgencyName IS NOT NULL
            SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N' AND AgencyName = @AgencyNameParameter '

        IF @StartDate IS NOT NULL
            SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N' AND StartDate = @StartDateParameter '

        IF @EndDate IS NOT NULL
            SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N' AND EndDate = @EndDateParameter '

        IF @Term IS NOT NULL
            SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N' AND Term = @TermParameter '

        EXECUTE sp_executesql
                @SQL, 
                @ParametersDefinition,
                @QuotationNoParameter = @QuotationNo,
                @AgencyNameParameter = @AgencyName,
                @StartDateParameter = @StartDate,
                @EndDateParameter = @EndDate,
                @TermParameter = @Term

    END
```

Comment: I am still getting an error as Incorrect syntax near '@SQL'. Not able to run your query

Comment: I just tried it on my DB and it works, please refresh the page and try again. It works without problems in my case so I guess there is something wrong undergoing on your DB.

Answer (score -1):

From the SQL side you can achieve by this way:

```
SELECT * FROM Qoutes AS q
WHERE (q.QoutationNo = @QoutationNo OR @QoutationNo IS NULL)
AND (q.AgencyName = @AgencyName OR @AgencyName IS NULL)
AND (q.StartDate = @StartDate OR @StartDate IS NULL)
AND (q.EndDate = @EndDate OR @EndDate IS NULL)
AND (q.Term = @Term OR @Term IS NULL)
```

Pass NULL value if it is not selected from the web page.

Comment: Mostly it works...
It works with the combination like Only Quotation number, Quotation number and AgencyName,

But it didn't work for the or clause like "quotation number or AgencyName"

Comment: Can you please share the few combination samples?

Comment: Added some combination Please check

Comment: 1 to 5 should work
for 6 to 9, Quotation No + Agency... When both will be matched then only it returns the record

Comment: @San Jaisy, Have you checked all your cases? Is it fulfilled with above query?

Comment: Above query gives the same result as the dynamic query. I don't understand why someone devoted it? It would be good if that person shared his/her view here, so all can understand what is wrong in the query?